# data frame to matrix without padding numerics

Tags: r, matrix

When converting a data frame to a matrix, R pads spaces into numeric columns:

```
> d=data.frame(x=c(10000,1),a=c("a","bbbbb"))
> as.matrix(d)
     x       a      
[1,] "10000" "a"    
[2,] "    1" "bbbbb"
```

the source code for `as.matrix.data.frame` shows this is because it uses `format` to convert to character (rather than `as.character`), so you get:

```
> format(d$x)
[1] "10000" "    1"
```

instead of

```
> as.character(d$x)
[1] "10000" "1"
```

Character columns aren't formatted with format so they don't get padded.

Is there an easy way to convert the DF to a matrix without padding? Better than running `str_trim` all over it?

Comment: May be `sapply(d, as.character)`

Comment: Not sure it's any better than `str_trim()` but `trimws(as.matrix(d))` works as well.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but any reason that you are using a matrix where columns are of different types? Also, for fun, add in a column of logical values....

Comment: Converting a data frame to JSON, want as simple a JSON format as possible. Data frames get decorated with column names and so on, whereas a matrix is converted as like `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]` (but quoted strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
as.matrix(format(d, trim=T))

#   x       a      
# 1 "10000" "a"    
# 2 "1"     "bbbbb"
```

Comment: So nobody else bothered putting a solution in an answer for three years so you get the tick and the points. I'd go with `trim=TRUE` though!

Comment: I was surprised to find it unanswered! :D